# XPATH ImportXML query, but no attributes

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Trying to extract the date out of this node

```
<time datetime="2017-11-26T14:03:58Z" title="11/26/2017 02:03  PM" data-short="1 dy">Yesterday at 02:03  PM</time>
```

I am trying to format the date into G Sheets with the following query:

```
//*[@id='elProfileStats']/ul/li[4]/span/time[format-datetime(@datetime,'[F], [D] [MNn]')]
```

So time is the last attribute, I've tried to select and format datetime within the node, but it doesn't work.

The ImportXML function errors in google sheets , 'Imported XML content cannot be parsed.'

I've tried :

```
//*[@id='elProfileStats']/ul/li[4]/span/time/@title
```

which returns 'Imported content is empty.'

```
//*[@id='elProfileStats']/ul/li[4]/span/time[not(@datetime)]
```

which returns 'Imported content is empty.'

Many thanks for any thoughts,

Answer (score 0):

There is something squiffy with your XPath. Those square brackets are for node-tests - basically, its a statement that acts to filter out the nodes in the path before the brackets.

You'll need to do something like this if you want to explicitly format the date strings. This works for me on your example:

```
format-dateTime(//some/path/time/@datetime cast as xs:dateTime,"[F], [D] [MNn]")
```

This transforms the string "2017-11-26T14:03:58Z" into:

```
Sunday, 26 November
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying
I'm very new to XPath and have tried to rely on Xpath 'helpers' and such extensions

I've been struggling to get a working Xpath, but interestingly
'//*[@id='elProfileStats']/ul/li[4]/span/' works

Would you be able to suggest resources for learning how to path this correctly?

Here is the WIP and armful of tries. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WrCEoVNETElr5AS2dzqEqA0bm_u1xJjQIF5DmMpmGNM/edit?usp=sharing